# Change Class Name

Tags: python, class

Is there a way to change the name of a class (not just the class objects, but the class itself)?

For example:

```py
class Foo:
    # stuff


obj1 = Foo()
# Code that renames Foo class to Food
obj2 = Food()

if obj1.some_value == obj2.some_value: # some_value is part of the Foo class
    print("The class has been renamed!")
```

If the code works, `obj1` and `obj2` should be the same. Is this even possible to do in python? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: ... You mean `Food = Foo`? Even then your two instances will not be equal unless you implement `__eq__` on your class.

Comment: Why would you need the name of a class to be changed? If your code for some reason relies on the names of classes, then it seems like this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'm wanting to know how python works. Is there a way to, not just assign `Foo` to `Food`, but to directly change the class so that referring to `Food` calls `Foo` and calling `Foo` doesn't work.

Comment: After you do `Food = Foo` do `del Foo`

Comment: I'm more looking to see if there is a way to directly change the name of the class, not just assign it to something else.

Comment: If this impossible, I would like to know

Comment: You can assign to `Foo.__name__` and `Foo.__qualname__`. That will change the class's idea of its own name, but won't allow you to call it using the new name.

Comment: @Cameron Why do you want to change the name? Virtually nothing (aside from extremely contrived code) cares about the name of the class.

Comment: If you want to know how Python works, ask about that directly.

Comment: It's more that I want to understand how reassignment works with classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the new name from the old name so you can call the new name. Use `del oldname` to prevent caling the old name. And change the `__name__` and `__qualname__` attributes of the class so that the new name will appear in type descriptors.

```
Food = Foo
del Foo
Food.__name__ = Food.__qualname__ = "Food"
```

Comment: So in other words, you can make a new class to mimic the old class, but you cannot directly change the name of the original class?

Comment: It's not making a new class. It's the same class, it has just been assigned to a new variable name. Just like when you assign a list or dictionary to another variable.

Comment: If you do `print(Foo == Food)` (before the `del Foo` of course) it will say True.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps me understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the class and delete the original:

```
class Foo:
    def test(self):
        pass


obj1 = Foo()

# Copy and delete original
Food = Foo
del Foo

obj2 = Food()
```

However `if obj1 == obj2` will not work because if references the class instance not the class itself.

Comment: If you print `type(obj2)` it will say that it's a `Foo`, not `Food`.

Comment: That is not copying the class; it is assigning the class to another variable.